# How to dynamically populate select box depending on data in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a select box which is filled using ng-repeat with data from an array. The array contains information such as first name, last name and user name. Per default, I want to display the first and last name in the select box. If these two Strings are empty, I want to display the user name instead. Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

My current HTML code that displays the first and last name remaining empty of those two values are empty:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
  <select   ng-model="ctrl.user">
     <option ng-repeat="option in ctrl.userList" value="{{option.userName}}"                            
        {{option.firstName}} {{option.lastName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My controller code snippet for the array:

```
var userList = [{"firstName": "Steve", "lastName": "Miller", "userName": "miller"}, {"firstName": "Anne", "lastName": "Jones", "userName": "jones"}, {"firstName": "", "lastName": "", "userName": "mrX"}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check any string in expression, if bother are not then show `option.userName`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <select   ng-model="ctrl.user">
      <option ng-repeat="option in ctrl.userList" value="{{option.userName}}"                            
        {{(option.firstName || option.lastName) ? option.firstName + ' ' +
     option.lastName : option.userName }}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the correct one using `||` because OP wants it to show username only if 2 other fields empty.

Answer (score 2):

Check this working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('MyController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $compile) {
            $scope.userList = [{ "firstName": "Steve", "lastName": "Miller", "userName": "miller" }, { "firstName": "Anne", "lastName": "Jones", "userName": "jones" }, { "firstName": "", "lastName": "", "userName": "mrX" }];
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <select ng-model="user">
            <option ng-repeat="option in userList" value="{{option.userName}}">{{(!option.firstName && !option.lastName)?option.userName:( option.firstName +' '+ option.lastName)}} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `ng-if` makes the `userList` re-ordered on the select options. option without first and last name will grouped to the last list regardless where the actual index is.

Comment: Yes, let me change it

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely help you:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in ctrl.userList" value="{{(option.firstName && option.lastName) ? option.firstName + ' '
     option.lastName : option.userName}}"                            
        {{(option.firstName && option.lastName) ? option.firstName + ' '
     option.lastName : option.userName }}</option>
```